# JQuery Ajax-Call with type: "POST" is received as "GET" by server

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, types

I have trouble with my first server communication experience and hope for help.

Following a tutorial I created an ajax-call for a webserver (cross-domain).  Everything went fine until i experimented with switching the type from "GET" to "POST": JQuery still sends get-requests (firebug-confirmed, server r_print() tested both $_POST and $_GET).

So the big question for me is: How do i teach $.ajax to send POST? (Yes, a GET might do, but this code does not what i want it to do and that hurts my feelings)

The PHP-side i checked with a simple HTML-form which sent a post with the expected results.

I as well added the line:

```
 jQuery.ajaxSetup({ jsonp: null, jsonpCallback: null});
```

Suggested in a similar answer without positive result.

**Server code (PHP) consists of nothing but:**

```
echo("alert('".print_r($_POST)." -- + -- ".print_r($_GET)+"');");
```

**JQuery-side:**

```
function executeRequest() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://server/script",
    data:  ({ username: "test" }),
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "jsonCallback",
    contentType: "application/json",
    jsonCallback: "jsonCallback",
});
 }
function jsonCallback(data) {
alert(data.username);
 }
```

executeRequest();

Every help or hint - both on improving my search-patterns as well as the specific problem - is very appreceated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Remove the lines "jsonp" and "jsonCallback.". If you want to use a callback, add a .done() function to the $.ajax, as per the $.ajax documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

JSONP inserts a script tag that executes Javascript from a different domain, and only supports GET requests, as POST is'nt possible with a script tag inserted into the DOM, no matter what you'd like to use.

Comment: haha a so simple answer. Thanks adeneo and Slaks! Learned something again.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP works by creating a `<script>` tag.
It is fundamentally impossible to send a JSONP POST.